# Projective bundles

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry

I am studying about projective bundles now. And I have the following doubts.

1) If we have an exact sequence of vector bundles over a scheme $X$,
$0\longrightarrow E'\longrightarrow E\longrightarrow E''\longrightarrow 0$, then what happens to the corresponding projective bundles. Is there some injective/surjective morphism between them

2) Also assuming that my guess is right, if $E''$ is a quotient of $E$, that is, $E\longrightarrow E''\longrightarrow 0$. Then $Y=P(E'')$ is a closed subscheme of $X=P(E)$. Then what is the ideal of $Y$?

I would be very thankful if someone clarifies these doubts. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Exact sequences of projective bundles don't make sense.

Comment: Ah I see, then can you tell me what the relation between surjective, injective map of vector bundles and their projective bundles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 2), let $\pi:X=\mathbb{P}(E)\to S$ be the natural map. We have a canonical surjection $\pi^*E\to\mathcal{O}_X(1)$ and thus a map by composition $\pi^*E'(-1)\to\mathcal{O}_X$. The image is the ideal sheaf defining $Y=\mathbb{P}(E")$.

Comment: can you tell me why this is so? Thanks!

Comment: It can be done many ways, and one way is to do this locally.